# keep default selected value in bootstrap multiselect

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I have use bootstrap multiselect 
my code is as below,

```
<select id="data" name="data[]"  multiple="multiple">

  <option value="100" <?php if($session == "1"){echo "selected";}?>>foo</option>
  <option value="101" <?php if($session2 == "1"){echo "selected";}?>>bar</option>
  <option value="102">bat</option>
  <option value="103">baz</option>
</select>

 $('#data').multiselect({
                     nonSelectedText: 'Select option',
 onDropdownHide: function (event) {}
});
```

here I have default selected value.on page load it shows me my default selected value.when I select another value (other then default selected). my "multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" this not append new value with default selected value and override it with new value although checkboxes are still checked.

and when I get value with

```
$("#data").val();
```

it only gives me value which are newly selected not give me value that I selected default. I want all checked value from dropdown and also all checked value should show in "multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default".

can any body help me for this?I will appreciate best answer.

Comment: I have follow this link to implement bootstrap multiselect and I have use first time  : http://www.jqueryfaqs.com/Articles/Multiple-Select-MultiSelect-DropDownList-with-CheckBoxes-using-jQuery.aspx .

Comment: or Is there any another way to keep selected value more then one?

Comment: Nevermind, I was wrong about `<select multiple>` :)

Comment: have you any idea ,for my issue?

Answer (score -1):

You could try using $_SESSION['variableName'] rather than $session. So that the content value still retain.

You could use this as your reference: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: This is not actually answering the question.

Comment: I have use $_SEESION and store it value in view page in $session

Comment: Create document.ready for jquery... so that the javascript will wait to load the elements before taking the value.